# How to add a conditional required field?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an ecto model for an address with this (simplified) schema:

```
defmodule Address do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "addresses" do
    field :zip, :string
    field :country, :string
    # snip
  end

  @countries_requiring_zip ~w(US) # snip

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(country), ~w(zip))
    |> validate_zip
  end

  defp validate_zip(changeset) do
    if get_field(changeset, :country) in @countries_requiring_zip do
      # ????
    end

    changeset
  end
end
```

I want to mark `zip` as required instead of optional, but only if the country is in a whitelist, but I can't figure out a clean way to write the validation.  How do I add that constraint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply define multiple casts too:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, ~w(country), ~w())
  |> cast_by_country(params)
end

defp cast_by_country(changeset, params) do
  case get_field(changeset, :country) do
    "US" -> cast(changeset, params, ~w(zip), ~w())
    _    -> cast(changeset, params, ~w(), ~w(zip))
  end
end
```

`get_field/2` will read a value from the changes and fallback to the struct one if there isn't one. This is the biggest benefit of changesets: it is just data structure and you can use regular Elixir code to do conditional checks, validations and so on. Straight-forward to write, read and test. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not an explicit function for requiring a field outside of `cast`. You can use the [validate_length/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_length/3) function and override the ':message' option.

```
validate_length(changeset, :zip, min: 1, message: "is required when country is US")
```